# What does ところ mean in this sentence?

Tags: words

I know ところ means place, but I can't get it here. Does ところ have another meaning?

ある学生に会う**ところ**です。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ところ in this case does not mean "place", it means "just about to".

ある学生に会うところです。
I am about to meet a student.

According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", page 496:
ところ: Someone/something is in a state where he/it is just about to do something, is doing something, has done something, or has been doing something.

Examples:
春江は晩御飯を食べるところだ。
Harue is just about to eat her supper.

春江は晩御飯を食べているところだ。
Harue is in the midst of eating her supper.

The dictionary also has some examples:
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/54376/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D/

2 〔ちょうどその時，場合〕
手紙を書くところだ
I'm going to write a letter.

皆そろったところで写真を撮りますよ
When everyone gets here, we will take a picture.

ちょうど顔を洗っていたところへ電話が鳴った
The telephone rang just as [when] I was washing my face.

もう少しで忘れるところだった
I nearly forgot.

笑っているどころではありません
This is no occasion for merriment.

危ないところを助かった
I had a narrow escape.

今のところは健康です
I'm quite well at the moment.

このところ暑い日が続いている
We have been having a spell of hot weather.

よいところへ来た，上がりなさい
You've come at the right moment. Come in.

今日のところは勘弁してやる
I will forgive you just this once.